# Find the file or line of code that is calling my bash script

Tags: bash, parent-child

I am trying to find what/where is calling my bash script. So far I've inserted "pstree -la" and "systemctl status" commands in my bash script. I see the parent process that calls my script, but it does not help me locate the file or the line of code that actually calls my script.

anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: You should be able to work backwards from the parent process. Look at the code for the parent process if necessary

Comment: @David : You did not say what programming language the program of the parent process is written, but if you can get hold of the source code - for instance if the parent is also a shell script -, you could manually inspect it or turn on the program trace to see what is going on.

Comment: I am on a new job. The software is using multiple languages (c, , python2, js, shell, html, css, php, etc..)I suspect the line calling my script is in a .cgi file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're on Linux, look in `/proc/$PPID/cmdline` to see how that program was invoked. Note that file uses a null byte to separate words.

```sh
read -r -d '' parentProgram < /proc/$PPID/cmdline
echo "I was invoked by '$parentProgram'"
```

If the full path to the parent program is not fully listed, use `locate` to help you search.

You can acquire all the arguments in the cmdline file:

```sh
mapfile -t cmd < <(tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/$PPID/cmdline)
declare -p cmd
```

Comment: When I use echo "SHELL invoked: " $(grep "^$USER" /etc/passwd), I get '/bin/ksh'            When I use read -r -d '' parentProgram < /proc/$PPID/cmdline and echo "I was invoked by '$parentProgram'" , I get 'sh'

Comment: The single quotes are preventing variable expansion.

Comment: David, look more closely into the /proc/$PPID/cmdline -- it seems what is invoking your script is another script, and the script name will be the 2nd null-delimited "line" in the cmdline file. The user's login shell has nothing to do with it.